# Jquery blueimp plugin start button disable

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

Result of what happens, the image remains on processing and the start button is disabled.I tried to implement the Basic plus JQuery upload but the files start button remains disable.
[image]

It supposed to work as the demo:
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html

[image]

Anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: can you provide your plugin initialization code, so we could look into the issue...